# SVG start size is 0 0

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm inserting an SVG element into HTML with JS. I want the element to have `width=100%` and `height=200px`. Then I want to insert a path into the SVG element. Path `d` depends on SVG element size, but it is 0 0 just after insertion. I've tried:

```
var board = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
document.body.append(board);
var h = board.height.baseVal.value; //appears to be 0
var w = board.width.baseVal.value; //appears to be 0
```

There is also this css:

```
svg {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
display: block;
}
```

No matter if there is `display: block`, the result is the same. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any event that fires when my element gets non zero height and width? Thank you!

Comment: `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')` just create empty svg. and svg element has no width or height witch are for HTML Dom for sizing the svg viewbox

Comment: width=100% of what ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for the `<svg>` `width` and `height` attributes is `100%`.
The IDL attribute you are accessing will reflect that.

What you want is probably more the bounding rect of your node, but in HTML, it will default to 300*150 if these attributes are not explicitly set (I don't remember exactly why, something to do with inline-replacedElements IIRC..., but it also concerns <canvas> <video> and <iframe> at least )

```js
var board = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
document.body.append(board);
console.log(board.width.baseVal.valueAsString); // "100%"

// what you want is the bounding rect
const rect = board.getBoundingClientRect();
const w = rect.width; // 300 (+2 border)
const h = rect.height; // 150 (+2 border)

console.log(w, h);
```

```css
svg {  border: 1px solid; }
```

If you want it to default to something else than 300*150, you'd have to set these attributes explicitly:

```js
var board = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
board.setAttribute('width', '100%');
board.setAttribute('height', '100%');

document.body.append(board);
console.log(board.width.baseVal.valueAsString); // "100%"

// what you want is the bounding rect
const rect = board.getBoundingClientRect();
const w = rect.width;
const h = rect.height;

console.log(w, h);
```

```css
svg {  border: 1px solid; }
```